# How to find hidden elements while web-scraping with node JS, Cheerio, Axios, and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, hidden, cheerio

Im looking for how i would get this format of data when web scraping:
How would I instruct it to grab content that is marked in the source code as:

```
 <div hidden="">https://doi.org/10.1016/S0272-7757(21)00078-9</div>
```

I have a working web scraping application that takes data in this format, taking the class data and pushing it into an array:

```
$('.js-article-title', html).each(function () {
            const title = $(this).text()
            articles.push({
                title
            })
```

How would I take this code and help me find this hidden data on the page? Please help im a beginner.

Comment: You can use `div[hidden]` to select a `div` with `hidden` tag.

Comment: thanks so much @Enve, how would i work this into the code? would it just be as a replacement of the current quote? do I still need a period before it?

Comment: I would have to see the rest of the html to know that. If the hidden div you are trying to select is a child of `.js-article-title` then you can use `.js-article-title div[hidden]`. If you want to select every hidden div in the page, then just `div[hidden]` without the class will work

Comment: Youre the best thank you! that totally worked!